# Regex remove space between characters but ignore space at the beginning

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I have HTML code that I would like to clean up with search/replace regex. I have many instances where I have more than one space between words that I want to remove with regex but I want it to ignore the HTML indents at the beginning of each line.
The expression \h{2,4} delete all space that are between 2 and 4 but how can I get it to ignore the indent at the beginning?
Here is a sample HTML code:

```
<tr>
  <td><strong>Vamos a   sentarnos.</strong></td>
  <td><strong>Let's sit   down.</strong></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>veamos    (ver)</td>
  <td>let's see (to   see)​</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this works for you. It replaces any spaces if there are more than 2 of them and they are not at the beggining of the line.

`(?<!^)\h\K\h+`

Replace by "nothing"

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pq4idK/1/)**

**Explained:**

```
(?<!^) # not a previous begin of line
\h     # one horizontal space
\K     # ignore previous match
\h+    # one or more horizontal spaces
```

**Optional approach**

`([^\n]\h)\h+` Replace by `$1`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pq4idK/2)**

or even: `([^\n][^\S\r\n])[^\S\r\n]+` (if `\h` is not supported) Replace by `$1`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pq4idK/3/)**

Comment: Great solution! I like both ideas: The negative lookbehind and the ignore match.

Comment: Thank you, I can see on the demo site that your solution is working perfectly. Unfortunately, the regex won't work in my Editor "TextSoap". Even the Dreamweaver editor won't recognize it. Do I have to make any changes for other editors?

Comment: I did a search online and dreamweaver is supposed to be PCRE compatible. Did you tick the 'use regular expressions' checkbox on dreamweaver?

Comment: I added other regexes that could work for some other non-pcre regexes

Comment: yes I have checked "use regular expressions" in dreamweaver and simple expressions work. I have now sent the developer of "TextSoap" an email with the different regex codes you've provided (Thank you a lot for this!!) so he can check it why it won't be working. TextSoap is also PCRE compatible.

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/GOxPpS/1

```
<td>.*?(\h{2,4}).*<\/td>
```

You could add the `<td>` tag strings to your regex. Then the search always will be inside the tags.

The whole query explanation can be found in the provided link:

> `<td>` -> matches the characters  literally (case sensitive)
>
> `.*?`  -> matches any character (except for line terminators)
>
> `*?`   -> Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
>
> `\h{2,4}` -> matches any horizontal whitespace character. Matches between 2 and 4 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Comment: Thank you for your solution! How would the replacement look like? Because if i leave the replacement empty, the whole sentence including the tags are gone.

Comment: As you can see on the example the part for replacing is a group. I don't know your tool or language but it should be possible to search for the group match, not for the full match. The group can be replaced by an empty string.